# In the react 3.0 whether to support async validation?It did not use redux-form.so ,can async validation of server be realized?

Tags: react-admin

Will react-admin3.0 support to perform validation from server? It seem to have removed redux-form in the form . So, how to perform async validation?. I do not have any idea. Can someone provide some solution for it? If I want to do async validate some field in the `<SimpleForm>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I was looking for a solution because since few days I'm using the newest version of react-admin with my new incoming projects.

After seeing zero responses to your question I spent last hours looking for a solution. I've built a simple plugin, called ra-remote-validator, that can help you with this requirement.

You can find more details here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-remote-validator

I hope this can help or, if you have news about this topic, I will appreciate any information!

Comment: In react3.0 the input is base-on final-react-form ,the  final-react-form can do validation from server(see https://codesandbox.io/s/wy7z7q5zx5), so as the react-admin form .validate  can be a async function.Such as TextInput can pass a async function which can validate on serve to the prop 'validate'.

Comment: Sorry but I think you are out of scope. We are talking about remote server validation, different from what you can do with client side validation. If the client is ok and the server return errors you have to handle different situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const availableValidate = resource => (
  property,
  filterId
) => async value => {
  if (!value) {
    return 'Required';
  }
  const result = await fetch.query({// i use graphQl ,you can use rest-api 
    variables: {
      filter: [{ property, operation: 'EQUAL', value }],
      page: { page: 0, size: 1 },
      sort: [{ property: 'id', direction: 'ASC' }],
    },
    query: gql`
        query ${resource}($filter: [SearchCriteria], $page: SearchPage, $sort: [SearchOrder]) {
          lists: ${resource}(filter: $filter, page: $page, sort: $sort) {
            content {
              id
              code
              name
            }
          }
        }
      `,
  });
  if (result.data.lists.content.length > 0) {
    const finalData = filterId
      ? result.data.lists.content.filter(ele => ele.id !== filterId)
      : result.data.lists.content;
    if (finalData.length > 0) {
      return `Unavailable ${property}`;
    }
  }
};
const validateField = availableValidate('deliveryTypes');// write a function for validate

  <Create {...props} title="Create">
      <SimpleForm redirect="list" toolbar={<CreateToolbar />}>
          <TextInput
            source="code"
            resettable
            validate={[required(), validateField('code')]}
         />
       </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
```